# Creating buttons with unique names through a for loop in Swift 4

Tags: uibutton

Im building an app with a complex UI that requires 45 buttons. For a variety of reasons, I am not using Interface Builder. In order to update properties for specific buttons, I need each of the buttons to have a unique name, (Btn1, Btn2, Btn3...) Here is the code that I am using:

```
let buttonsArray = ["Btn1",  "Btn2",  "Btn3",  "Btn4",  "Btn5",  "Btn6",
                    "Btn7",  "Btn8",  "Btn9",  "Btn10", "Btn11", "Btn12",
                    "Btn13", "Btn14", "Btn15", "Btn16", "Btn17", "Btn18",
                    "Btn19", "Btn20", "Btn21", "Btn22", "Btn23", "Btn24",
                    "Btn25", "Btn26", "Btn27", "Btn28", "Btn29", "Btn30",
                    "Btn31", "Btn32", "Btn33", "Btn34", "Btn35", "Btn36"]
for button in buttonsArray  {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: nextx, y: nexty, width: btnsiz, height: btnsiz))
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled  = true
    button.alpha = 0.05
    button.tag = tagnum
    tagnum += 1
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.997, green: 0.645, blue: 0.014, alpha: 1.0)
    button.setTitle(notesarray[count], for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.991, green: 0.607, blue: 0.33, alpha: 1.0)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
    btnarray[count] = false
    setNextX()
    element += 1
    count += 1
}
```

When a button is pressed it is recognized. I have assigned a unique tag number. I want to be able to update properties based upon the button name (Btn1) such as:
Btn1.isUserInteractionEnabled  = true. I get the error message "Use of unresovled identifier 'Btn1'. How do I get the name specified as I could in Interface Builder with IBOutlet?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid IBOutlets are an Interface Builder only thing - hence the 'IB' in the name 'IBOutlet'.

If you want to get a reference to a subview of view, you can use the [UIView tag](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag) property. I see that you are already using this tag property, passing it 'tagnum', which looks like it increments for every button, similar to the names in the ButtonsArray.

For example, if you want to get the button with tag 1, you could request it like this:

```
let Btn1 = self.view.viewWithTag(1)
```

You could then do what you're suggesting:

```
Btn1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

An aside, I would recommend you name your variables beginning with a lower case letter to [follow best practices](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/):

> **Follow case conventions.** Names of types and protocols are
>   UpperCamelCase. Everything else is lowerCamelCase.